# ASP.NET MVC intranet site deployment

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, deployment, intranet

Howcome I deploy my intranet `ASP.NET MVC` project?

What I've got so far:

- project itself;
- several client machines connected in a workgroup and server;
- `IIS Express 7.5`, `SQL Server 2008 R2 Express` installed on a server.

It should be mentioned that though it's odd and unusual but server is just a machine without (even) server OS installed. *Please note that it's not mine idea and is the environment I've got at the moment*

I've read the instruction http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg703322(VS.98).aspx but it describes situation when you have `Web Developer` installed on the same machine.

Please help!
And Thanks!

Comment: My article doesn't assume you have any dev tools on the web server. You just need to have the web server set up correctly and deploy the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the 100% manual approach, you might be able to access the remote web server via VS  if authorization/permissions is lined up properly (much simpler, basically you just hit deploy):

1. Install IIS
2. Install .NET Framework 4
3. Install MVC
4. Register ASP.NET with IIS (just to be safe run it again)
5. Create Website via IIS Management Console (use a new directory for the website)
6. Put your files inside the new directory
7. Make sure permissions are setup properly
8. That's it

Comment: So the main thing is to have IIS installed (and properly configured) and is to have a project. And without VS... Should it be something like a `bin` deployement. I've learnt a bit that it is quite complicated process

Comment: I mean.. dependencies on `ASP.NET MVC`.

Comment: You don't need bin deployment as such is only necessary when the server does not have MVC installed, but since you are in control of the server you can just install MVC via the installer. Afterwards just copy the files it's fairly straight forward. I've updated the answer to also include .NET + MVC installation.